# Backbone, different extent for the same Model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, model-view-controller

I try to understand how Backbone work and what is the best form of do a modular code.
I am making a app with different pages. In one of this page I have two different part, one tree and one list. I need to use the same tree in a future page, and this is the problem. How can do it?

I'm thinking in different extent of the same model. But I don't know if I can do this.
In another way I can do different model for the different part of the page.

What is the best form to do this?

Ok I try to do this:

create new mainModel in the controller

```
define(function(require) {
    var controller = function() {
        this.initialize = function() {
            // global variables
            var $ = require('jquery'),
                _ = require('underscore'),
                Backbone = require(['backbone']);
            // module variables
            var mainmodel = require('mainModel'),
                view = require('page/views/index');
            // execute
            this.mainmodel = new mainmodel();
            this.view = new _view({
                model: this.mainmodel
            });
        };
    };
    return controller;
});
```

create two new model into mainModel

```
define(['treeModel', 'pageModel'], function(treemodel, pagemodel) {
    return Backbone.Model.extend({
        // init
        initialize: function() {
            // create new model
            this.treemodel = new treemodel();
            this.pagemodel = new pagemodel();
        }
    });
});
```

But I can't access to the new model in the view.

Comment: You could use it with Marionette.js . There is a lot of tutorials online.

Comment: Not really sure what your asking but you can create a *base* model and then extend your other models from that.

Comment: I can't use Marionette.js because I need to reuse the maximum code  as possible. The new application uses ready-made pages and need to be in the same way. The app don't use Marionete. Thank

Comment: I don't create the app. I'm only make new pages for new app. The think is that I will use the tree in the future. I need one Model or expand the same Model with the data used for the tree and another Model to the different part of the page (This change in the future). All this is for reused this tree in the future. Thank Jack

Comment: to minimize the code, better if you opt for Marionette